# Android AdMob implementation play-services problem

Tags: android, admob, build.gradle

I'm trying to add AdMob to my app. I added the line below to `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
```

However, after syncing, I started to get the error below:

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-28:19 to override."

What should i do?

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bartech.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}    
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.bartech.myapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.bartech.myapp.quiz1"/>
        <activity android:name="com.bartech.myapp.summary"/>
        <activity android:name="com.bartech.myapp.info"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is happening because you are using **Support Libraries** such as `support:appcompat`, `support:support-v4` along with the latest version of the `play-services-ads` (18.2.0) which already migrated to AndroidX.

So, you are getting this error because your app is using Support Library but `play-services-ads` is already using AndroidX.

In order to fix:

1) Migrate your app to AndroidX (recommended). More info [HERE](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

2) Use an old version of play-services-ads (such as `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'` for example.)

This second option may fix your issue because `play-services-ads:16.0.0` was still using Support Library as well.

Comment: I migrate my app to AndroidX and everything is working now. Thanks!

Comment: Terrific. Good to know!